# Javascript - Working with Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm learning about creating cookies with Javascript and have created this experimental log in page. It works 100% but I want to be able to display the users username and password. Can this be done with cookies in Javascript? I have attached my current code below:

```
function displayCookies(){
    if (GetCookie("user") || GetCookie("pass")){
        document.regform.usercookie.value = GetCookie("user");
        document.regform.passcookie.value = GetCookie("pass");
    }else{
        document.cregistrationform.usercookie.value = "Make sure you have signed up!";
        document.registrationform.passcookie.value = "Make sure you have signed up!";
    }
}
function createCookies(){
    var username = document.registrationform.user.value;
    var password = document.registrationform.pass.value;
    var date = Date();
    SetCookie("user", user);
    SetCookie("pass", pass);
    alert("You have registered!");
    alert("Welcome back" + username ". Your last visit was" + date);
}

function reloadPage() {
  location.reload(); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: What if they visit from another device, or even another browser on the same device? Best to handle this *server-side*.

Comment: If you *do* decide to do this client-side, don't use cookies. Cookies are for communicating information between the client and server, and they piggyback on every HTTP exchange. For purely client-side information, use [web storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm aware the best approach is server-side but at this point I'm not setting up a database to store username or passwords. I just want to create a cookie to display the last visit in the current browser I am working in

Comment: Then again, don't use a cookie, use web storage. See the link above, and probably more helpfully, [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).

Comment: I don't see the "date" variable you mentioned.

Comment: @floverdevel I removed it because when I tried running my code to test it nothing would work at all

Comment: Then I think you should show us the actual code that you try to run if you want us to be able to help you :)

Comment: @floverdevel apologies! I'll update the question. Please see the code I was trying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First function contains "c" in front of registration form? That should be removed:

```
function displayCookies(){
    if (GetCookie("username") || GetCookie("password")){
        document.registrationform.usernamecookie.value = GetCookie("username");
        document.registrationform.passwordcookie.value = GetCookie("password");
    }else{
        document.registrationform.usernamecookie.value = "Please register!";
        document.registrationform.passwordcookie.value = "Please register!";
    }
}
```

Duplicate question of:
[How do I create and read a value from cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)